# `ImpressPages PageImage Plugin dont't work

Tags: impresspages

I have problem with PageImage plugin.

After adding slot to my theme:
`<?php echo ipSlot('pageImage'); ?>` - image not displayed
Plugin created link to image: 
`<img src="file/2014/09/06/filename.png" alt="">`

Maybe IP trying read file from:

```
http://testsite.com/pl/file/2014/09/06/filename.png
```

Maybe i have bad settings modrewrite?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have a fix for you. Does it work?

https://github.com/impresspages-plugins/PageImage/commit/b55e4a5ac1d17c65415aa0ee5d911fc3b39b57af

Comment: I've also updated the package on ImpressPages market. So you can just install it from there http://market.impresspages.org/plugins/PageImage